# creating a fake origin point in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine

in the figure below you'll see two separate points in time and three object. You can also see the direction object C is facing.

[image: diagram]

I am trying to replicate a false point of origin for object B at the center of object A, which will then orbit around A based on the direction of object C in the BGE using python. parenting object B and A are not allowed, in fact no parenting is allowed in this example, neither is rotating object B based on the rotation of object A.

how would I accomplish this in the bge using python?

It took me a while to figure out just how to articulate this, and to keep it clear what I want to do. I thanks for any help in advanced.

EDIT: here's what I have so far, this goes on an always sensor to python actuator on object B. It however doesn't set the angle of the object properly.

```
    #------------------------------------------
    print("------------------")
    import math
    import bge
    from bge import logic
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    contrlr = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = contrlr.owner
    obj = scene.objects['C']

    #horizontal
    x0= obj.worldPosition.x
    y0= obj.worldPosition.y
    y= 0
    x= 0
    (dx, dy) = (x0-x, y-y0)
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(float(dy), float(dx)))
    if angle < 0:
        angle += 180

    #vertical
    z0= obj.worldPosition.z
    x0= obj.worldPosition.x
    z= 0
    x= 0
    (dx, dy) = (x0-x, z-z0)
    angle2 = math.degrees(math.atan2(float(dy), float(dx)))

    angle=angle
    angle2=angle2+180

    if angle2 < 0:
        angle2 += 180

    print("A1A2",angle,angle2)
    #get C's angle from the centerpoint /\
    #############################################
    #now set the objects angle
    import sys
    import bge
    import random
    import math
    from bge import logic

    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    contrlr = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = contrlr.owner
    obj = cont.owner

    angle2=angle2-90
    A=angle*-1
    T=angle2

    R=own['radius']

    obj.worldPosition.x = R*math.sin(T)*math.cos(A);
    obj.worldPosition.y = R*math.sin(T)*math.sin(A);
    obj.worldPosition.z = R*math.cos(T);
    print("tapos",T,A,obj.worldPosition)
```

hope this edit helps.

Comment: I dont know BGE but can you place in an empty and parent your object to the empty? That should solve your problem. Your anchor point should be the empty.

Comment: "parenting is not allowed in this example"

Comment: The only thing I can think to do really is to create a circle, and then match the object in the allowed points in the circle to the camera. And I don't really know how you'd do that regardless it doesn't seem like a very effective method, any suggestions?

Comment: @Frederick and what is supposed to be the result of your question, a satellite of a planet or objects spinning around another object?

Comment: B follows C while spinning around A. So both I guess?